# Can't list SQL databases like directories with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to list databases with PowerShell. I'm able to use Inkoke-Sqcmd cmdlet, but I can't list databases with this command:

```
dir SQLSERVER:\SQL\myserver\sqlinstance\Databases

Get-ChildItem : No se encuentra la ruta de acceso 'SQLSERVER:\SQL\serverr2\serverr2\Databases' porque no existe.
En línea: 1 Carácter: 4
+ dir <<<<  SQLSERVER:\SQL\serverr2\serverr2\Databases
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (SQLSERVER:\SQL\serverr2\serverr2\Databases:String) [Get-ChildItem], ItemNo
   tFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand
```

I already tested this in my local computer, but failed on my server.
Is something missing on my installation? I have Windows Server 2008 R2, SQL Server 2008 R2, PowerShell 2.0

**Edit:**
Get-Host cmdlet shows me this information:

```
Name             : ConsoleHost
Version          : 2.0
InstanceId       : c1976472-19c0-439e-a4f6-debe59a18616
UI               : System.Management.Automation.Internal.Host.InternalHostUserInterface
CurrentCulture   : es-MX
CurrentUICulture : es-ES
PrivateData      : Microsoft.PowerShell.ConsoleHost+ConsoleColorProxy
IsRunspacePushed : False
Runspace         : System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.LocalRunspace
```

I also found that my instance of SQL Server is Microsoft SQL Server 2008 (SP1) - 10.0.2531.0 (X64) and not SQL Server 2008 R2 as I thought

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Can't list SQL databases like directories with PowerShell**

Be sure to load the SQL Server Snap-Ins (Add-PSSnapin) to support the appropriate commands, etc. Below are examples of the syntax with for either **default instance** or **named instance** of SQL Server, and where to plug that detail in on the PS commands.

**Important Note:** The `serverr2\serverr2` in your PS logic may be incorrect, it may be the default instance where you'd use `DIR SQLSERVER:\\SQL\Serverr2\Databases` only. Mirror this part to match how type that to connect to the database engine from SSMS perhaps of your SQL Server instance.

---

So two possibilities to try based on your error (*see below examples how to `Add-PSSnapin *sql*` if needed first though*):

- **Default Instance:** `DIR SQLSERVER:\\SQL\Serverr2\Databases | Select Name`
- **Named Instance:** `DIR SQLSERVER:\\SQL\Serverr2\Serverr2\Databases | Select Name`

---

### Example SQL Server Named Instance

```
Add-PSSnapin *sql*
DIR SQLSERVER:\\SQL\<SQLServerName>\<InstanceName>\Databases | Select Name
```

### Example SQL Server Default Instance

```
Add-PSSnapin *sql*
DIR SQLSERVER:\\SQL\<SQLServerName>\Databases | Select Name
```

---

### Further Reading and Resources

- [**Add-PSSnapin**](http://ss64.com/ps/add-pssnapin.html)
- [**Select-Object**](http://ss64.com/ps/select-object.html)

---

[**Difference between Default instance and Named instance in SQL Server**](http://dupdupduptop.blogspot.com/2012/11/what-are-difference-between-default.html)

> **What are difference between Default instance and Named instance in SQL
>   Server?**
>
> A SQL Server installation is referred to as an instance. Up to and
>   including SQL Server 7.0, only one installation of SQL Server was
>   possible on a server, but that restriction didn’t suit a number of
>   deployment scenarios that customers required, including
>   high-availability and consolidation.
>
> With the release of SQL Server 2000, multiple installations of SQL
>   Server were possible on a single server and were known as SQL Server
>   instances. SQL Server 2008 continues with this model and with very few
>   changes. A default instance has much the same profile that SQL Server
>   installations have had in past; you install SQL Server and then
>   connect using the computer name of the server. Your Windows Server can
>   only have one computer name, so you can only use it to connect to one
>   SQL Server instance. This is called the default instance.
>
> If you install additional instances of SQL Server, these are referred
>   to as named instances. You connect to them using the
>    format. For example, if you have a server
>   named PLUTO and you install a named instance named SQL1, you would
>   connect to that instance using PLUTOSQL1. If you installed another
>   named instance called SQL2, you would connect using PLUTO SQL2. If you
>   had a default instance installed, you would connect using PLUTO.
>
> Each instance is completely independent of any other instance and has
>   its own set of services, databases, and configuration settings. All
>   the components of a single instance are managed together, and service
>   packs and patches are applied to all components within an instance.
>
> During the installation process you have to specify a unique instance
>   ID, which is used to define the directory structure, registry
>   structure, and service names for that instance. This is new in SQL
>   Server 2008. By default, the instance name that you specified is used
>   as the instance ID. For the default instance, MSSQLSERVER is used as
>   the instance ID.

As per [Mr_LinDowsMac](https://superuser.com/users/79287/mr-lindowsmac) . . .

> I workaround like this: `$databases = (DIR SQLSERVER:\\SQL\serverr2 |
>   SELECT Databases -ExpandProperty Databases | SELECT Name,Owner,Urn)`.
>   Since I can't use WHERE, I just use $databases = $databases -match
>   "SERVERR2\SERVERR2" to filter to that specific instance. –
>   [Mr_LinDowsMac](https://superuser.com/users/79287/mr-lindowsmac)

Comment: @Mr_LinDowsMac You likely have 1-3 potential issues (potentially 1, 2, or all 3) from what I see, **`1.`** load the `Add-PSSnapin` first and then run the `DIR` command **`2.`** Be sure you have **TWO `[\\]` backslashes**  in this part of this command `DIR SQLSERVER:\\SQL` **`3.`** you just need to ensure you are pointing to either the correct **default** or **named** instance of SQL Server in your configuration.

Comment: DIR SQLSERVER:\\SQL\server\namedinstance\ I get a list with Roles, Databases, Endpoints, Roles, etc... But can't DIR inside them.

Comment: I did that from the beginning, the actual problem is that it doesn't work. However, I missed that part of `Add-PSSnapin`. I didn't run it because I'm not sure if it was related, and because it works without \Databases

Comment: No, Sorry, it doesn't work really. It is just listing me the instances installed. But I still not able to list Databases.

Comment: The SQLCMD -L lists my instance in UPPERCASE, but it doesn't work anyway. Now, I'm trying to workaround with this: `DIR SQLSERVER:\\SQL\serverr2 | SELECT Databases -ExpandProperty Databases | SELECT Name,Owner,Urn`, but it is listing me Databases from another instance that I don't want. I'm unable to Filter it

Comment: I workaround like this: `$databases = (DIR SQLSERVER:\\SQL\serverr2 | SELECT Databases -ExpandProperty Databases | SELECT Name,Owner,Urn)`.Since I can't use WHERE, I just use `$databases = $databases -match "SERVERR2\\SERVERR2"` to filter to that specific instance.